# Testing $.get("..").then() in Karma(w/ Mocha)

Tags: jquery, karma-mocha

I am trying to test the following component's controller lookup function:

```
lookup () {
    if (this.index == 1) {
        return $.get('http://www.stackoverflow.com').then(res => {
            this.index = res.data;
            return res;
        });
    }
}
```

To test it, this is what I am doing:

```
controller.lookup();
```

Most of the time, it is only executing this line

```
if (this.find.index == 1) {
        return $.get('http://www.stackoverflow.com');
}
```

and not executing `.then(..)` promise.

I guess, during some of the runs, I am getting response from the jquery "get" request, hence, the "then" promise is executed, but is there a way to wait until the "get" response is received or to fake the response? 
(Tried using sinon spy, but no luck so far)

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recommended way is to mock/spy on the api calls. You can do something like this,

```
sinon.stub($, 'get').returns({then: function(callback) {
     callback({user: 'ABC'});
}});
```

Here is working [example](http://codepen.io/jegadhu84/pen/VmBYwZ)

Instead of using manual callbacks, you can use with promise.